# Hadith about fears of the hypocrites who argue using the Quran giving wrong interpretations?

Tags: hadith, authenticity

أَنَّ أَخْوَفَ مَا أَخَافُ عَلَيْكُمْ ثَلَاثٌ : جِدَالُ مُنَافِقٍ بِالْقُرْآنِ ، وَزَلَّةُ عَالِمٍ ، وَدُنْيَا تَقْطَعُ أَعْنَاقَكُمْ

The greatest fear that I have for you are three: The argumentation of a hypocrite using the Quran, the blunder of a scholar, and duniya cutting your necks.

[Hadiith from Dar Qutniy, (Sunan al-Daraqutni”) and other compilations]

Is this hadith authentic?

Comment: I could not find this hadith in Sunnan Al-Daraqutni. If you have its reference number or chain of narration from your source in Sunnan Al-Daraqutni, please provide it. It is in Al-Mu'jam Al-Awsat by Al-Tabarani, though. Is this the one you are referring to?

Comment: @III-AK-III it is apparently a quote from Ihya' 'ulum ad-dyn ad-Daraqutni quoted it in his 'ilal on the authority of Mu'ad ibn Jabal (also ibn al-Jawzy in his al.'ilal al mutnahiya), ad-darimi quoted it as a saying of 'Omar, it is basically a saying of a sahabi and has some sahih sanad I found it in takhrij ahadith al-Ihya'.

Comment: @Medi1Saif - Yes, the only connection between this hadith and Al-Daraqutni was his quote in Al-'Illal Al-Mutanahiya fi Al-Ahadith Al-Wahiya (العلل المتناهية في الأحاديث الواهية) by Ibn al-Jawzi, in which Al-Daraqutni said the hadith is mawqoof at Sho'ba through 'Amr ibn Murrah, and not a hadith of the Prophet (ﷺ). I could not find any other connection to Al-Daraqutni, though.

Comment: @III-AK-III and in majma' az-zawaid (take a look at #881 and #882 and maybe #883) http://islamport.com/d/1/mtn/1/81/2959.html it seems to be based on narrations from at-Tabarani.

Comment: I guess this is the source of your quote https://iloveimamrabbani.wordpress.com/tag/maliki-jurist-qadhi-abu-bakr-ibn-al-arabis-ahkam-al-quran/ ... i found similar quotes by other sahaba in al-muwafaqat  الموافقات http://sh.bib-alex.net/osolfkh/Web/11435/005.htm

Answer (score 2):

This hadith, as attributed to the Prophet ﷺ is very weak. There is, however, a *hassan* (good) narration — with similar wording — that is attributed to [Mu'adh ibn Jabal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muadh_ibn_Jabal) in [*I'lām al-Muwaaqi'īn*](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33173/1251) by [Ibn Qayyim al-Jawziyya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Qayyim_al-Jawziyya) and in [*Al-Mu'jam al-Awsat*](https://al-maktaba.org/book/28171/9097) by [At-Tabarani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Tabarani):

> وَبِهِ: حَدَّثَنِي اللَّيْثُ قَالَ: قَالَ يَحْيَى بْنُ سَعِيدٍ، حَدَّثَنِي أَبُو حَازِمٍ، عَنْ عَمْرِو بْنِ مُرَّةَ، عَنْ مُعَاذِ بْنِ جَبَلٍ، عَنْ رَسُولِ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ قَالَ: إِيَّاكُمْ وَثَلَاثَةً: زَلَّةَ عَالِمٍ، وَجِدَالَ مُنَافِقٍ، وَدُنْيَا تَقْطَعُ أَعْنَاقَكُمْ. فَأَمَّا زَلَّةُ عَالِمٍ فَإِنِ اهْتَدَى فَلَا تُقَلِّدُوهَ دِينَكُمْ، وَإِنْ زلَّ فَلَا تَقَطَّعُوا عَنْهُ آمَالَكُمْ. وَأَمَّا جِدَالُ مُنَافِقٍ بِالْقُرْآنِ، فَإِنَّ لِلْقُرْآنِ مَنَارًا كَمَنَارِ الطَّرِيقِ، فَمَا عَرَفْتُمْ فَخُذُوهُ، وَمَا أَنْكَرْتُمْ فَرَدُّوهُ إِلَى عَالِمِهِ. وَأَمَّا دُنْيَا تَقْطَعُ أَعْنَاقَكُمُّْ فَمَنْ جَعَلَ اللَّهَ فِي قَلْبِهِ غِنًى فَهُوَ الْغَنِيُّ
>
> <sub>*— **NOTE**: My own translation, so treat with care:*</sub>
>
> Narrated by Mu'āth ibn Jabal that the Messenger of Allah ﷺ said: "Beware of three: the slip of a scholar, the argumentation of a hypocrite, and this world cutting your throats. As for the slip of the scholar, if he guides, do not blindly copy [saying we do as this scholar does] and if he slips, do not lose hope about him. As for the argumentation of a hypocrite using the Qur'an, the Qur'an has a light that illuminates its road: take what you recognize, and what you deny, ask a scholar [of the Qur'an] about it. As for the world cutting your throats, whoever keeps Allah in his heart will be the rich one.
>
> <sub>— [*Al-Mu'jam al-Awsat*, Vol. 8, pp. 307-308, hadith 8715](https://al-maktaba.org/book/28171/9097)</sub>

In the gloss, Ibn Qayyim al-Jawziyya said that:

- The hadith as *mawqūf* by Mu'ādh (not attributed to the Prophet) has a *hassan* (good) chain of narration, and was documented by Wakī' in *Al-Zohd* (#71), Abu Dawūd  in *Al-Zohd* (#193), Abu Na'īm in *Hilyat al-Awliyā'* (5/97), Ibn Hazm in *Al-Ihkām fi Usūl al-Ahkām* (6/72-73/180), Ibn 'Abd al-Barr in *Jāmi' al-Bayān* through Sho'ba (1872), and Al-Lalika'i in *Sharh Usūl I'tiqād Ahl as-Sunna wa al-Jamā'a* (1/122) through another narration chain.
- The hadith as *marfū'* (attributed to the Prophet) is not authentic with a very weak narration chain as Ad-Daraqutni said in *Al-'Illal Al-Mutanahiya fi Al-Ahadith Al-Wahiya* (6/81/992) and through At-Tabarani in *Al-Mu'jam al-Kabīr* (20/282), *Al-Mu'jam al-Awsat* (6575), *Al-Mu'jam as-Saghīr* (1001), and in *Al-Fawā'id* by Abu al-Qāssim Tammām (10), and Ad-Dailami in *Mussannaf al-Firdaws* (1/93). Al-Haithami documented it in Majma' az-Zawā'id and said it had a severed chain of narration, in addition to having 'Abdul-Hakam ibn Mansour whose hadith is forsaken.

I have the same (or quite similar) hadith to the one you quoted was mentioned unattributed in [*Kanz al-'Ummāl*](https://al-maktaba.org/book/2677/11598), [Al-Qawl al-Muharrar](https://al-maktaba.org/book/33706/108), and in [Jāmi' al-Ahādīth](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1438/3157).